# I have problems with Android NDK, errors are below

Tags: android, go, fyne

I am packaging with Fyne, but I am having problems while packaging to Android. I tried two methods and the errors are as follows:

`no compiler for arm was found in the NDK (tried ). Make sure your NDK version is >= r19c. Use` sdkmanager --update `to update it`

and

`no Android NDK found in $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle nor in $ANDROID_NDK_HOME`

I tried:

`fyne package -os android -appID com.example.myapp` -> no Android NDK found in $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle nor in $ANDROID_NDK_HOME

`ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Users/ahmetaffanebcioglu/Library/Android/sdk/ndk fyne package -os android -appID com.example.myapp` -> no compiler for arm was found in the NDK (tried ). Make sure your NDK version is >= r19c. Use `sdkmanager --update` to update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found for those who are looking for an answer to this question.

```
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/Contents/NDK fyne package -os android -appID com.example.myapp
```

But if NDK is in a different place, I don't know.